# Difference of MAX() and MIN() of a table returns Aggregate difference instead of unique difference over a selected period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to monitor the expense of 3 students with their respective IDs every day for 15 days. I came up with this code, but it gives the total expense for 15 days, not the day by day expense.

for example: if student `101` spends 10$, 15$, 32$ on days 1,2, and 3 respectively, it shows 57$ on all days as supposed to 10$ on day 1, 15$ on day 2, and 32$ on day 3.

```
SELECT
    Student_id
    , Expense
    , Cal_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(Expenditure * 1.0) OVER (PARTITION BY Student_id) - MIN(Expenditure * 1.0) OVER (PARTITION BY Student_id) AS "Expense"
            , CAST(DATEADD(mi, 330, date_time) AS DATE)                   AS Cal_date
            , Student_id                                                  AS "Student_id"
        FROM
            Table1
        WHERE
            Student_id IN (101, 102, 103)
            AND DATEADD(mi, 330, date_time) > DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE())
    ) A
GROUP BY
    Student_id
    , Expense
    , Cal_date
ORDER BY
    3, 2, 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not able to get your logic but one thing is sure that your window function is not correct.

You need to replace

```
OVER(PARTITION BY Student_id)
```

With

```
OVER(PARTITION BY Student_id, CAST(DATEADD(mi,330,date_time) as date) )
```

Or dont use window function at all as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(Expenditure*1.0) - MIN(Expenditure*1.0) AS "Expense", 
       CAST(DATEADD(mi,330,date_time) as date) as Cal_date, 
       Student_id as "Student_id"
  FROM Table1
 WHERE Student_id in (101, 102, 103)
   AND dateadd(mi,330,date_time) > DATEADD(day,-14, GETDATE())
Group by Student_id, CAST(DATEADD(mi,330,date_time) as date)
```

Comment: this works `OVER(PARTITION BY Student_id, cast(dateadd(mi,330,date_time) as date))` Thank you